# Store bullet point unicode characters in Mysql and UTF8

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, coldfusion, lucee

I am reading data from a CSV text file using Coldfusion and inserting it into a table. The database is UTF8, and the table is UTf8.

This string `•Detroit Diesel series-60 engine` keeps getting stored in the Description field as

`â€¢Detroit Diesel series-60 engine`. (This is what I get from the database, not displayed in the browser.)

I can manually insert the string into a new record from the command line, and the characters are correctly preserved. UTF8 must support the bullet character. What can I be doing wrong?

Datasource connection string:

```
this.datasources["blabla"] = {
      class: 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver'
    , connectionString: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blabla?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&jdbcCompliantTruncation=true&allowMultiQueries=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=true'
    , username: 'nottellingyou'
    , password: "encrypted:zzzzzzz"
};
```

CREATE TABLE output, minus several columns

```
CREATE TABLE `autos` (
  `VIN` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Description` text,
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

In addition, I've run

```
ALTER TABLE blabla.autos
MODIFY description TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Full code of import file here: https://gist.github.com/mborn319/c40573d6a58f88ec6bf373efbbf92f29

CSV file here. See line 7: http://pastebin.com/fM7fFtXD

Comment: Looks like a characterset conversion going on somewhere. Are you sure that's what's being stored, or is that whas is being returned on a web page? The problem could be the encoding before it's sent to the database, either the characterset on the database connection, or even reading the CSV file. Possible solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485224/coldfusion-character-encoding-issue

Comment: Let's see the connection string.  It needs to specify utf8.

Comment: That github link does not show utf8 at all.  What is the command to do the IMPORT?  If it is `LOAD DATA`, does it have a clause about `CHARACTER SET`?

Comment: As mentioned, it could be going wrong at several places. Output the raw CSV string. If the character looks okay, the INSERT is the likely problem. [Verify the *column* charset is really UTF8 and try using `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" ...>` (for unicode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875295/coldfusion-inserting-arabic-persian-characters-to-mysql/25877815#25877815).

Comment: _Looking OK_ is not sufficient.  Sometimes browsers try to _fix_ things like "double encoding".  Getting the HEX is conclusive.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I said *likely*, but you are totally correct. I was trying to avoid writing a book in the comments as the topic of unicode and/or CF + MySQL + Unicode was already covered in the archives several times ;-)

Comment: @spencer7593 yes, this is the exact string I copied from the database table. I updated the question with the connection string.

Comment: @RickJames that gist file is a Coldfusion script which reads the CSV file, converts it to an array, then INSERTs each row into the database.

Comment: @Leigh It seems as if Lucee does not support CF_SQL_NVARCHAR, because I get an "unknown types value" error when I attempt it.

Comment: @coderMe - Oh, the tags said ColdFusion so I thought you were using ACF ;-)  I cannot verify it now, but was under the impression Railo/Lucee supported nvarchar too.  Did you do what Rick suggested above, and check the actual hex/ascii value of the string *before* it is inserted into the db? That would tell if the problem occurs when reading the value from the file versus on the db side.

Comment: Thanks so much @Leigh, Rick James, and spencer7593! This was definitely a characterset conversion going on before insertion into the database. I apologize for such a misleading question.

Answer (score 1):

In my CFML script, I tried dumping the data per suggestion from @Leigh and @Rick James. I then saw that the characters are garbled BEFORE insertion into Mysql. Based on this, I realized I needed to specify the `charset` when reading the file.

```
<cffile
    action="read"
    file="#settings.csvfile#"
    variable="autodata"
    charset="utf-8">
```

Result: `•Detroit Diesel series-60 engine`. This can now insert correctly into the database.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  One more tidbit in the never-ending list of utf8 fixes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#other_computer_languages

Comment: @RickJames - Heh, you were right. Next time I will stick to writing my usual "book-o-comments" ;-)