# Display Russian data from mysql with coldfusion

Tags: mysql, utf-8, coldfusion

I have a mysql database set up with the Character Set as utf8 and the Collection set as utf8_general_ci.

I can see the Russian text in the database is all fine.

I have added a `<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">`
in the coldfusion pages. If I type in russian text directly in the cfm page, it displays fine in the browser.

However, If I us a cfquery to pull in the data to display it in the browser, it displays incorrectly i.e. ÐŽÐ‘Ð.

my cfquery is a very simple...

```
<cfquery name="getStatic" datasource="#session.odbcname#">
SELECT  *
FROM    static_id
WHERE   static_displayname = 'home'
AND     static_status = 'online'
</cfquery>
```

and then use a cfoutput to display the data `#getStatic.data#`.

any ideas on how to get the data pulled in to display correctly?

Thanks

Comment: cfprocessingdirective doesn't affect dynamic queries. 1) Did you try specifying character set in the dsn url? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29595897/8895292 2) You said "I have a mysql *database* set up with..."  double check the actual *table and column* inherited the correct settings.

Comment: Did you try my 2 suggestions above? If you're not getting the right output, then 1 or more of those settings probably isn't what you think they are...  If you haven't already, double check the column settings first `SELECT * FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'static_id'`.

Comment: Hi Ageax, thanks for your input. Sadly no joy, I have added various connection strings form your suggested link and others with no joy. I have also created new tables in mySQL with Character Sets utf8 and utf8mb4 and also with a Collection of utf8_general_ci and utf8mb4_general_ci and sadly no joy. :-(

Comment: That is very odd.. Maybe it is something specific to the hosting environ? I tried those settings for grins ... and outputting Russian text works no problem.  Aside from asking your host, have you tried it on another machine? Easy enough to spin up a dev instance and try it there.

Comment: Hi Ageax, many thanks for your help, it looks like your idea of trying another machine works - it looks like the machine I was using was inputting the Russian text fine but for what ever reason it was not importing into the mySQL correctly. Even thou I could view Russian text in my mySQL client.

Comment: Ohh, that makes sense... output doesn't work cause it's already corrupted! Glad you figured out the problem. Was the "import" done with CF queries or some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your page.

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "utf-8">
```

Or better yet, add it to the `onRequest()` event of your `application.cfc` if you need it on every page.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfprocessingdirective.html

Comment: Hmm, got a downvote.  If anonymous downvoter cares to to explain what's wrong with my answer I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: Hi user9263373, thanks for your answer. sadly I Have tried using the `cfprocessingdirective` but it only works if I have russian text directly on the cfm page. Sadly its not working when I pull in text from the mySQL database.

Comment: @elixireu Gotcha.  Now I see why my answer was bad... It's clearly in your post and I didn't see it, so my apologies for answering without reading.  Take a look at this as it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly

Comment: Here's another that might help as well https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Comment: Hi, many thanks user9263373 for your help on this, sadly I have tried them all but with no success. I have sent a message with the hosting company to see if there is an issue with mySQL as it is all in utf-8mb4.

Comment: @elixireu  Here's another you can try https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2017/12/how-to-use-unicode-for-chinese-characters-in-coldfusion-and-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

`ÐŽÐ‘` is 'Mojibake' for `ЎБ`

In UTF-8, the hex is `D08E D091`.  If that is treated as `latin1`, hex `D0 8E D0 91` means `ÐŽÐ‘`.

But, it could also be "double-encoding", and the hex in the table is `C390 C5BD C390 E28098`.  Please do `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to see which you have.

Double-encoding is a silent error -- usually everything looks ok, while the stored value is wrong.

Look for 'Mojibake' in [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for a list of things to check in your code.

(For Cyrillic, `CHARACTER SET utf8` and `utf8mb4` act identically.  They differ primarily for Emoji and Chinese.)

My skimpy notes on ColdFusion say

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">

<cffile
action="read"
file="#settings.csvfile#"
variable="autodata"
charset="utf-8">
```

(Ugh.  I counted them.  I have notes on 45 3rd-party packages such as ColdFusion.  Forgive me if I don't speak authoritatively on one of them.)